# Android: Optimize nested layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, optimization

I have created a layout and I'm experiencing a lot of performance issues in my gridview.
I have read that nested layouts can prevent smooth scrolling:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.bestpick.bestpickapplication.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/LightGrey"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/menu_item_image"
            android:background="#77000000"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <RatingBar android:id="@+id/menu_item_avg_rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:stepSize="0.1"
                    android:rating="0"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text= "("
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/menu_item_number_ratings"
                    android:text= "0"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text= ")"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I achieve the same result without so many levels of layouts?

Edit: Picture of the layout
[image: Picture of the target layout]

Comment: also could you so us a pic of how you want the final layout, so we can think of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left out the superfluous things (e.g. text color, etc) so that you can see how the layout attributes are used to produce the effect you want. This layout uses just 6 views and one level of nesting -- if you really want to minimize the number of views, it's possible to do it with 5 views, but this is the cleaner approach.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >

    <com.bestpick.bestpickapplication.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <View android:background="#77000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/menu_item_name"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_avg_rating"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_number_ratings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu_item_avg_rating" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/menu_item_avg_rating" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that for the TextView next to the RatingBar, the intention is that you use a string resource with `%1$d` and use `getString(R.string.whatever, some_integer)` to get the appropriate text. See [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) if you don't know how that works.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps 
My output 
  [image]

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:background="#770"
            />
        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#770"
            android:orientation="horizontal">    
            <RatingBar android:id="@+id/menu_item_avg_rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:stepSize="0.1"
                android:rating="0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_number_ratings"
                android:text= "(0)"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your post.
The Text + rating actually has to "overlay" on top of the image, so that both bottoms coincide. How should I edit your code?
Thanks!